# is there a way to read wordpress database remotely?

Tags: node.js, wordpress, azure, node-mysql

I am trying to pull all the post from my wordpress with nodejs. The database is in azure and trying to connect remotely from my machine.so is there any way to do it?please help me? Thanks for your time

Comment: SO is not for tutorials and recommendations. Please narrow your question to specific code, so we can help you.

Comment: Hi,@Krishna joshi, have you solved your problem?

Comment: Yes I solved my problem Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You can get your database connection info on Azure portal, please login [Azure manage portal](https://ms.portal.azure.com), find and click your Wordpress application in `App Services` list, then click `All settings`=> `Application settings` => scroll down to `connection string` section, click `Show connection string values`, then you can get the database connection string in the below list.
[image]

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. When setting up the Wordpress, you set the database connection. Now, for remote access to that DB, you should take the connection string and, using that string, connect to the database. There is almost nothing specific - you may use the official [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt715784.aspx).